# Subjonctif ou indicatif à la forme négative et interrogative

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Les tournures suivantes sont suivies de l'indicatif :

> il est vraisemblable, il est convenu, il est probable, il est sûr, il
> est vrai, il est évident, il est clair, il est visible, il est bien
> connu,...

Si on a la forme négative ou la forme interrogative de ces tournures, est-ce qu'on emploiera toujours l'indicatif ?

Par exemple :

> Il n'est pas vrai qu'il est mon ami.
>
> Est-il probable que vous viendrez demain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le subjonctif indique le doute, l'indicatif l'affirmation.

Après *il est vraisemblable/probable*, les deux modes sont donc possibles suivant ce sur quoi on veut insister :

> Il est vraisemblable/convenu/probable qu'il viendra. (on y croit)
>
> Il est vraisemblable/convenu/probable qu'il vienne. (on en doute quand même)

Avec les autres phrases proposées, l'indicatif est attendu puisqu'on insiste sur la réalité du fait.

Avec les formes négatives, le subjonctif est le plus souvent utilisé puisqu'on exprime un doute :

> Il n'est pas vraisemblable/convenu/probable/sûr/évident/clair qu'il vienne.

mais :

> Il (ou *ce*) n'est pas vrai qu'il vient. (il est faux qu'il vient)

Avec les formes interrogatives, on rencontre là aussi l'indicatif avec *vrai* :

> Est-il (ou est-ce) vrai qu'il vient ?

et le subjonctif avec les autres phrases :

> Est-il vraisemblable qu'il vienne ?

Donc:

> Ce n'est pas vrai qu'il est mon ami. (Ce n'est pas vrai que c'est mon ami)
>
> Est-il probable que vous veniez demain ?

Il existe beaucoup de subtilités dans le choix de l'indicatif et du subjonctif. Voir par exemple http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-l-emploi-du-subjonctif-le-fran-ais-tel-qu-en-lui-meme-76928562.html